PSD calculated without sampling rate $F_s$
Professor Steve Brunton mentioned in Denoising Data with FFT that fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n is computing the power at each frequency. However, the code says it is PSD as seen in PSD = fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n. Is it Power or PSD or neither of them?

if you take complex number $\lambda$ times $\lambda$ conjugate, this is essentially gives you the magnitude of $\lvert \lambda \rvert ^2$, and that is what we are doing here with fhat. We are computing each Fourier coefficient squared, and we get a vector of power at each frequency.


From what I understood from How to scale FFT and PSD in Matlab,  Density of Power Spectrum should involve $ \frac{\lvert \lambda \rvert ^2} {n F_s}$ where $F_s$ is sampling rate. But fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n = $\frac {\lvert \lambda \rvert ^2}{n}$ does not have $F_s$ in it.

Then, what is fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n actually? Or do I misunderstand something and it is indeed PSD?

There is an endless discussion to be had about PS vs. PSD. The PS is the integral of the PSD. To compute the PS, we often normalize by the bandwidth of the FFT bandpass filter, although this changes with windowing and averaging, etc. The PSD computes the time averaged power at each center frequency. The PS integrates this by assuming a constant power in a finite narrow bandwidth, and that each bandwidth is constant, so the integral becomes the area of a rectangle.


However, the code says it is PSD as seen in PSD = fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n. Is it Power or PSD or neither of them?

It's neither. It is kind of a power spectrum, and kind of a PSD, missing a $1/n$ factor to make it a proper power spectrum, and a $1/f_s$ factor to make it a proper PSD (see this answer).
In the context of the video, it does not matter too much the scaling, since the Power Spectrum is used only to find coefficients that are below a certain threshold. You can change the scaling, and simply change the threshold.

Thanks for the answer, but as a newbie, I am confused why there can be different scalings applicable to calculate a PSD? For me standardizing by normalization has only one way such as Z score is by diviging by Std. It can be only divided by Std, nothing else, hence seeing different scaling can be applicable confuses me. Also I see divide by Fs in the linked answer, so why Professor Brunton is not dividing by Fs? If you can help in layman's word, much appreciate it.

A few things: 1. You'll see a lot of interchangeability in signal processing terms. You'll see spectrum used for power spectrum. You'll see Periodogram used for Spectrogram, etc.  This can be very confusing. The same thing will (unfortunately) happen with terms such as Power Spectrum and Power Spectral Density. The fact is, these are different in what they try to measure (see the link in my answer). The scalings I refer to in there are the most commonly used, because they make sense mathematically to stay true to what these two things measure (narrow-band vs broadband power).


Scaling can be important when measuring quantities that are used straightly for their absolute value (as opposed to relative). For example, if you want to know the physical power of some signal acquired through some sensor and ADC and ran through an FFT, there's only one way to scale these FFT values to get back to the actual physical value. However, when dealing with relative values, such as the context of your question, you can normalize exactly however you want. You can normalize between 0 and 1, divide by the max, or do a Z-score. As long as it fits your requirements.



Professor Brunton is taking a loose approach to his definition of the PSD. Like I said in my answer, it does not matter in this context, since he only uses these calculated values relatively to each other, via a threshold. Still loose though! I've edited my answer to reflect that.


Finally, this reference is in my opinion the best on this topic (section 9).

Thank you so much. Now I started understanding the picture.
